# Get the difference of values between two mysql selects

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have two working MySQL queries:

```
SELECT MAX(value) as value FROM data WHERE value_id = '123' AND DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 1)
```

and the second query:

```
SELECT MAX(value) as value FROM data WHERE value_id = '123' AND DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 2)
```

Both queries are nearly the same. They give me back the highes value of the day before (2017-10-24) and the highest value of the day before - the day before (2017-10-23).

Now i now, mysql does not implement a minus function. But i have to calculate the difference. I red about the NOT IN function but i'm not able to use this function correctly...

thx for helping!

Comment: What difference? What minus what? The differnce between the highest values? Just subtract them--read about scalar subqueries.

Comment: everything fine my question has been answered

Comment: Please edit your question to be clear. Someone guessed at what you meant & they & you got lucky. That doesn't make your question helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement in single query to get the max value and then in outer query do you subtraction

```
SELECT value1 - value2 as diff
FROM (
    SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN value ELSE 0 END) as value1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 2) THEN value ELSE 0 END) as value2
    FROM data 
    WHERE value_id = '123'
) a
```

In case you have to no idea which value will be greater the above can produce result as a negative value also to deal this issue add CASE in outer query as well

```
SELECT CASE WHEN value1 >= value2
       THEN value1 - value2
       ELSE value2 - value1
       END as diff
FROM (....) a
```

Comment: @user3882511 There was extra comma after value2 in inner query now removed